# String a bold / Italic

Tags: c#, web

Estoy intentando dividir una cadena de una consulta por intros, y despues de eso verificar si hay etiquetas de Negrita o Italica, si las hay esa cadena pasara a ser Negrita/italica dependiendo de la situacion. Lo hago pero no funciona, alguien puede decirme porque?

```
 TableCell tc8 = new TableCell();

                Table t8 = new Table();
                string text8 = dr["OBSFX"].ToString();
                char d = '\n';
               string[] substr8 = text8.Split(d);
                foreach (string s in substr8)
                {
//La string s puede tener o no una parte escrita en bold (<b>asdf</b> ghjk ) por ejemplo
//La parte bold es la que tiene que estar en negrita obviamente
                    TableRow trS = new TableRow();
                    TableCell tcS = new TableCell();

                    tcS.Text = s;
                    if (s.Contains("<b>")&& s.Contains("</b>"))
                    {
                        tcS.Font.Bold=true;
                    }
                    if (s.Contains("<i>")&& s.Contains("</i>"))
                    {
                        tcS.Font.Italic = true;
                    }
                    trS.Cells.Add(tcS);
                    t8.Rows.Add(trS);
                }
                tc8.Controls.Add(t8);
```

He probado tambien con

```
  Table t8 = new Table();
                string text8 = dr["OBSFX"].ToString();
                char d = '\n';
               string[] substr8 = text8.Split(d);
                //separar por "enter"
                foreach (string s in substr8)
                {
                    TableRow trS = new TableRow();
                    TableCell tcS = new TableCell();
                     Label l = new Label();

                    if (s.Contains("<b>") && s.Contains("</b>"))
                    {
                        int n = s.IndexOf("<b>");
                        int nc = s.IndexOf("</b>");
                        l.Text = s.Substring(0, n);
                        l.Text += "<b>" + s.Substring(n + 3, nc - 3) + "</b>";
                        l.Text = s.Substring(nc + 4);
                        tcS.Controls.Add(l);

                    }
                    else {
                        l.Text = s;
                        tcS.Controls.Add(l);

                    }
```

Pero aun asi, sigue sin entrar en la comprobacion, es como si no detectase las etiquetas de Bold

Tambien con las expresiones regulares que me puso @DanMiranda y nada :(
 Otra de las comprobaciones que he realizado es la siguiente:

```
 foreach (string s in substr8)
                {
                    TableRow trS = new TableRow();
                    TableCell tcS = new TableCell();
                     Label l = new Label();
                    if ((s.IndexOf("<b>")!=-1 )|| (s.IndexOf("</b>")!=-1))
                    {
                        int n = s.IndexOf("<b>");
                        int nc = s.IndexOf("</b>");
                        l.Text = s.Substring(0, n);
                        l.Text += "<b>" + s.Substring(n + 3, nc - 3) + "</b>";
                        l.Text = s.Substring(nc + 4);
                        tcS.Controls.Add(l);

                    }
                    else if ((s.IndexOf("<i>") != -1) || (s.IndexOf("</i>") != -1))
                    {
                        int n = s.IndexOf("<i>");
                        int nc = s.IndexOf("</i>");
                        l.Text = s.Substring(0, n);
                        l.Text += "<i>" + s.Substring(n + 3, nc - 3) + "</i>";
                        l.Text = s.Substring(nc + 4);
                        tcS.Controls.Add(l);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        l.Text = s;
                        tcS.Controls.Add(l);

                    }
```

mi desesperacion aumenta gradualmente :|

Comment: Hola Geraniego. te sugiero convertir tu ejemplo a un [mcve] siguiendo las pautas en ese enlace. No creo que sea difícil hacerlo en tu caso. Esto tiene la ventaja que nos permite reproducir tu problema. Y también sería bueno que seas más detallado cuando dices que *no funciona*.

Comment: Bien, te explico, digamos q trabajo en un sitio que no puedo sacar informacion de aqui. por otro lado, me devuelve una cadena con muchas pautas, y las voy separando en diferentes casillas, pero algunas de esas lineas estan marcadas com bold o como italic, y tengo que mostrarlas en italica o bold. en estos momentos estoy utilizando el objeto Literal para ver si consigo hacerlo de esa manera

Comment: ¿Leístes el enlace que te dejé?

Comment: Opss ni lo vi XD

Comment: @sstan no ha sido demasiado aclaratorio, soy novato en stackoverflow y suficiente con que se formular preguntas, prometo que mas adelante ire mejorando mis preguntas, como he ido haciendo estos dias :D

Comment: ¿Este código se ejecuta y después realiza un postback?, ¿Le has puesto un breakpoint a tcS.Font.Bold=true; para ver si esta cambiando la propiedad Bold?

Comment: Hola Geraniego. Me alegra que estés participando en el sitio y que tu deseo es de seguir mejorando.  Para ayudarte con esto, hay excelente información en [el centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) que te puede servir tanto para esta pregunta como para las próximas. Un saludo.

Comment: @DanMiranda si, y resulta que ni siquiera entra en el if, asi que la comprobacion esta mal hecha, pero no encuentro nada que pueda ayudarme, por eso pido "sopitas".

Comment: Ya Esta todo Solucionadooo!!!! Era un error de la base de datos, no del codigo. Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra colaboracion!!!

Comment: Ahora aunque sea alguien que lo busque en internet tendra diferentes soluciones correctas con las que hacer sus trabajos :D

Answer (score 0):

Realiza las comparaciones con expresiones regulares, son mas exactas y fáciles de mantener.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Busca etiquetas b en mayusculas y minusculas.
        string boldRegex = @"<(B|b)>.*<\/(B|b)>";

        // Busca etiquetas i en mayusculas y minusculas.
        string italicRegex = @"<(I|i)>.*<\/(I|i)>";

        string text8 = "<i><B>unTextodePrueba</b></i>";

        if (Regex.Matches(text8, boldRegex).Count > 0){
            // Is Bold
            Console.WriteLine("Is Bold");
        }

        if (Regex.Matches(text8, italicRegex).Count > 0){
            // Is Italic
            Console.WriteLine("Is Italic");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @DanMiranda. Justo salgo ahora del curro, lo miro en casa y mañana te digo